# Hibernate - Connection hangs

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I'm getting these warnings in my application, and it takes a long time get the response from database calls like 10-15 minutes. But is works fairly with slow response time, the problem is this same application works in my friends machine with fast database calls and no hangs under same configurations, even it worked in my machine before it get crashed. I couldn't figure out the reason behind this issue

Here's the logs with warnings

```
Aug 6, 2010 10:04:14 AM net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
WARNING: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Database changed to TEST_DATABASE
Aug 6, 2010 10:04:14 AM net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
WARNING: SQL Warning: 0, SQLState: 
Aug 6, 2010 10:04:14 AM net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
WARNING: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Changed database context to 'TEST_DATABASE'.
Aug 6, 2010 10:04:14 AM net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
WARNING: SQL Warning: 0, SQLState: 
Aug 6, 2010 10:04:14 AM net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
WARNING: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Language changed to us_english
Aug 6, 2010 10:04:14 AM net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
WARNING: SQL Warning: 0, SQLState: 
Aug 6, 2010 10:04:14 AM net.sf.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
WARNING: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Changed language setting to us_english.
Aug 6, 2010 10:10:04 AM org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.admin.StatisticsLogger statistics
INFO: 10:05:00 - 10:10:00, s:3:0.01/s, r:0:0.00/s, a:23.33ms/0.00
```

My system is

- Ubuntu 9.04
- Apache tomcat 5.5.27
- Hibernate 3
- Ant 1.7.0
- JDK 1.5.0_12
- MyEclipse 7.5 as the development tool.

Comment: Did you switch on verbose logging somewhere?

Comment: @John no I don't think so, I just made the same configuration that I had earlier but one thing changed the Ununtu version earlier it was 8.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to various sources, these `SQL Warning: 5701` (Changed database context) and `5703` (Changed language setting) are informational and should just be ignored(!).

From the [Thread: SQLstate(01000) vendor code(5701)](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2860651&tstart=0):

> The 'changed database context' message
>   is just one of the chatty
>   informational messages that SQLServer
>   has historically returned to the
>   client, which are universally ignored.
>   The JDBC driver must make any
>   non-exception DBMS message available
>   via a SQLWarning. Ignore it unless
>   you're surprised that your default
>   database context is Madimak. The cause
>   of the message is that the initial
>   context of a new connection is
>   actually master, until the DBMS
>   changes it to the user's default
>   context.

This is confirmed in [ODBC and SQL Server (SQL Server 2000) - Connecting to a Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197373(SQL.80).aspx).

But I'm not sure the slowness is related to these "warnings". My understanding of the above is that it is not.

Could you actually show your connection string? Just in case, the reference is [Building the Connection URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx).